# TitanGraph slows down on commit()

Tags: titan

I am creating Titan-Graph through Java. Dynamo-db local is as a back-end. My problem is , on graph.tx().commit() it takes more time  when i am creating 400+ vertices in graph. Time taken by commit() is about 10-15 minutes.
My titan configurations are as follows :

```
BaseConfiguration conf = new BaseConfiguration();

    conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager");
    conf.setProperty("storage.dynamodb.client.endpoint", "http://localhost:4567");
    conf.setProperty("storage.batch-loading ", "true");
    conf.setProperty("storage.buffer-size", "10000");
    conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache", "true");
    conf.setProperty("index.search.backend", "elasticsearch");
    conf.setProperty("index.search.directory", "/tmp/searchindex");
    conf.setProperty("index.search.elasticsearch.client-only", "false");
    conf.setProperty("index.search.elasticsearch.local-mode", "true");

    TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(conf);
```

please suggest me the solution for improving titan performance.

Comment: do you mean that your commit size is 400+ or that once your graph gets to a size of 400+ any commit you make takes this extended period of time?

Comment: i m creating 400+ vertices through java code and in last i had commit(). this commit() takes so much time. i have not any created graph in database.

Comment: what happens if you attempt to commit your transaction after each vertex you add? how is the speed with that approach?

Comment: attempting commit after each vertex that also takes time for committing.In short,total time for commit after each vertex had been added = commit after all vertex had been added. so how to increase my speed??

Comment: generally speaking, batching your commits with Titan is preferred from a performance perspective, but as you see equal performance either way it would indicate that something else is a problem and i'm sorry to say that at the moment, i'm not sure what that could be.